# Hibernate update query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, sql-update, dao

I have table with one primary key (auto increment) and three columns except that primary key column

S.No EmpId EmpName Month salary

```
1   1700   xxxx    Jan   17000
2   1701   yyyy    Jan   70000
3   1700   xxxx    Feb   16750
4   1702   yyyy    Jan   70000
5   1700   xxxx    Mar   17000
6   1700   xxxx    April 16000
```

This table contains details about employee names and his/her monthly salary details,
I need to update the salary of employee xxx in Jan Month.

How can i do this in hibernate by using session.saveorupdate method?

Comment: Dont want to perform this by update query..

Comment: Yes, you can do using `saveorupdate` method. did you face any issue in it?

Comment: Can u able to write the code for this problem?

Comment: Slightly OOT, but this this table (schema) is not properly normalized...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are working with persistent "employee" objects, I think something like this should work out.

```
Transaction t = session.beginTransaction();
employee.setEmpId(id);
employee.setEmpName(name);
employee.setSalary(newSalary);
...
session.saveOrUpdate(employee);
System.out.println("Successfully updated");
t.commit();
```